# Is there another way to upload Images to an SP PictureLibrary?

Tags: image-upload

I'm currently using Micorsoft.SharePoint.Client version 14.0.4762.1000. Unfortunately, this package does not contain the necessary tools to upload an image to a Picture Library. In order to do so, I have to download Microsoft.SharePoint version 15.0.0 (only available) from NuGet. But upon calling dependency to this package, my application goes into:

> Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code)

problem. Any solution?

Comment: What SharePoint version do you connect?

Comment: SharePoint 2010

Comment: New version would not support sp 2010, so that could be your problem. Please, try approaches, described on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: @RustamIsmagilov you pointed me to the right answer. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of Rustam Ismagilov pointing to [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010/) is the correct answer. Here was my approach:

```
public async void UploadFileToSpDocLibAsync(string listTitle, string atchmtFilePath, Action<bool, string> callback = null) {

    if (!File.Exists(atchmtFilePath)) {
        callback?.Invoke(false, "File not found");
        return;
    }

    try {

        await Task.Run(() => {

            // spsite is absolute uri of the SpSite
            using (var clientContext = new SPC.ClientContext(spsite)) {

                var web = clientContext.Web;

                var newFile = new SPC.FileCreationInformation {

                        Content = File.ReadAllBytes(atchmtFilePath),

                        Url = Path.GetFileName(atchmtFilePath)

                };

                SPC.List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);

                SPC.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);

                clientContext.Load(uploadFile);

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            }

        });

        callback?.Invoke(true, string.Empty);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        callback?.Invoke(false, ex.Message);
    }

}
```